# The meaning of "table worthy"

Tags: word-usage, meaning-in-context, suffixes

Does "table worthy" mean something that is good enough to be put on the table? Thank you!

> **Bread That's As Tableworthy As Your Turkey**
>
> This Thanksgiving, turn your side into your centerpiece with our new Pumpkin Seed & Raisin French Baguette. Pick up a baguette from Sept 28-Oct 4 to earn 2x Breadcrumbs.
>
> Put a fresh twist on your classic family tradition. It's a tasty offer you don't want to miss!

[image]

Comment: What's the source of this image? Can you link it?

Answer (score 9):

The suffix -[worthy](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/-worthy) is a fairly productive suffix. It can create new words with the meaning "deserving of", or "suitable for".

So by analogy with words like "creditworthy" (deserving of credit) and "seaworthy" (suitable for the sea) you can have ad hoc words like "tableworthy" which would mean "suitable for, or deserving of being on the table". Or more specifically in this context, "deserving of being part of a Thanksgiving meal"

see [English terms suffixed with -worthy](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Category:English_terms_suffixed_with_-worthy) (and feel free to create "[tableworthy](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/tableworthy)" if you have the time.)

Answer (score 3):

Yes. Here, it also means more...

[**-worthy**](https://www.wordreference.com/definition/worthy) (suffix)

> -worthy is used to form adjectives with the meaning "deserving of, fit for":
>
> *news + -worthy → newsworthy* (= fit for the news);
>
> *trust + -worthy → trustworthy.*

So, *tableworthy* is a formed adjective via the *-worthy* suffix. It means *deserving of being served at the table*.

But, to explain the meaning in detail, you have another pattern at work with this word:

[**As … as**](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/as-as) (adjective pattern)

> We use as + adjective/adverb + as to make comparisons when the things we are comparing are equal in some way:
>
> *The world’s biggest bull is as big as a small elephant.*

The *as [adjective] as* adjective here uses your word *tableworthy*.

> as tableworthy as your turkey

A [Thanksgiving turkey](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thanksgiving_dinner#Turkey) is the pinnacle, most celebrated, central dish at the table. If one were to server *bread as tableworthy as your turkey* for a Thanksgiving dinner, that must be amazing bread!