Should I create my own word, for example "questionworthy", when I write in English?
I know newsworthy is used to describe an event that deserves reporting (or to be reported?), therefore I wonder if I can describe a question worth asking in this forum questionworthy. That's completely based on my own logic and I have never heard of it before.
So, is questionworthy a usable word? Should I make up words in my writing this way?

I'm not sure a question can be questionworthy. Perhaps a word, or a grammatical concept, or something that you could create a question about, but not the question itself. Just like what's newsworthy is the event, and not the piece of news or the reporting about it.

If it's already a question, you can ask "Is this a good/worthy question?" If not, "Is it worth asking?"

(which sort of demonstrates the pitfalls of word formation - of course you can do that, that's how languages evolve, but you need to have pretty solid familiarity with how the individual affixes, morphemes and roots are used otherwise in English in order for your neologism to even be comprehensible, much less natural).

You can do as you like as long as it falls within the genius of the language. But really, would we ask if some question is worthy of being asked? I guess you could.

Does this answer your question? The meaning of "table worthy"

If you think a new word is required, it's worth checking whether it already exists and, if so, whether it has the meaning that you require. Google Ngrams can help you with this. In this case, the word has been used.... by Heidegger and Nitsche. https://www.google.com/search?q=%22questionworthy%22&lr=lang_en&sca_esv=f1470b44e75781e4&tbs=cdr:1,cd_min:2017,cd_max:2019,lr:lang_1en&tbm=bks&ei=xx1XZrSpI-Wa4-EPlOWj-A0&start=10&sa=N&ved=2ahUKEwj0qJrR7LKGAxVlzTgGHZTyCN8Q8tMDegQIEBAE&biw=1490&bih=762&dpr=1.25

The general principle is obviously that learners should be extremely cautious about "inventing" new terms, because they're so much more likely to get things wrong than native speakers.
Here's the full (subscription-only) Oxford English Dictionary definition for the relevant suffix...

-worthy  (combining form)
Forming adjectives with the sense ‘deserving of what is specified by the first element’, as blameworthy adj., noteworthy adj., praiseworthy adj., etc.

Although I can easily guess1 what OP intends his neologism to mean, it should be fairly obvious that it doesn't really fit the pattern of the three examples above, which mean should be blamed / noted / praised.
The existing English word for the corresponding should be questioned sense is questionable, but that's obviously not the meaning OP intends.

It certainly doesn't help that blameable , notable, praisable are all "more or less" acceptable synonyms for the OED's examples, but things fall apart when we try to apply the pattern to question (questionworthy can't mean questionable).
In any case, apart from "That's a questionworthy question!", I can't really see where OP's neologism might be useful. And as all politicians know, the idiomatic standard there is "That's a good question!"

1 Thanks to @Lambie's comment, I now realise there are at least two possible meanings for OP's neologism questionworthy (describing an actual question which is worth asking, or someone's presentation which merits the audience asking questions afterwards).
Which just goes to show what can go wrong when you make up words, even if you think the meaning is obvious!

questionworthy would mean: worthy of a question. That guy's presentation is not even questionworthy.

Fair enough. I didn't think of that possible meaning, so I guess I'll have to edit my answer to say I can't easily guess what OP intends his neologism to mean. In which case it's effectively irrelevant what any of us (including OP) think it might mean. It's not a standard English word with a standard meaning. End of story.

English usage gives one the freedom to create new words by analogy, especially if no apt word already exists. Often when such coinages are made the coiner will put the word inside quotation marks on its first use in their text. Be careful, though, as such coinages can be cringeworthy.

You can't make up a word without defining it. So I would only make up a word if I were going to use it repeatedly throughout a document. The first time you use it, you should define it so that everyone understands exactly what you mean:

Let's call a question that is worthy of being asked (e.g., meets the forum criteria, is not trivial) "questionworthy."

Then you can use that word as much as you want in the rest of the document. If you're only using it once, since you have to define it the first time, it doesn't really make sense to create it.
Valid might be a good substitute (a valid question).

Of course, all words must have been made up by someone at some point in time.  But as an English learner you normally avoid this.
In the particular case "questionworthy" already has some use. It is used to describe something that worth asking a question about.

One weird character was "Pops".  Let's ignore the questionworthy relationship he had with his student,...

(The speaker suggests it would be worth asking the question "is this relationship ethical?") If a native speaker used it like that I'd probably just think it was a bit odd, but it makes sense and not think more of it.  If an English learner did the same, it would seem like a mistake.
Creating new words is "incorrect" from the point of view of tests and there is too much risk of making your English sound unnatural.  So I'd have to recommend not creating new words. Instead, you should combine words.  You can say.  "Something that is worth questioning". You are then using standard English, and are clearer. This is better English.

questionable relationship there. Tests are not a judge of one's English.

Tests are used to judge one's English.  Even for native speakers, it is better not to invent new words in an ad hoc manner. English works by putting words together in sentences, rather than making new words from morphemes (it tends to be analytic rather than agglutinative)

https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/343280/the-meaning-of-table-worthy

Ah, the past, what a place to be in.
